# Car/RSU Region of Transmssion in OMNeT++

Tags: routes, protocols, omnet++, inet

I would like to implement a routing protocol for VANET where **Vehicles and RSUs can exchange messages only if they are in each other's region of transmission**!

Where can I implement this? In the omnetpp.ini configuration file or in the application layer (UDPBasicApp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Veins* framework is what you are looking for. It provides vehicular network simulation based on OMNeT++ and SUMO and also includes RSUs. You can find a download link [here](http://veins.car2x.org/), a tutorial [here](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) and answeres to some common questions [here](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I already implemented my own Vehciles and RSUs using the INET Framework. I am using veins to connect with SUMO and generate traffic. I am stuck where do I need to edit in order for them to work how I want them to (the routing protocol).

Comment: That heavily depends on your routing protocol and on your application. Probably you have to implement it in your application or in a lower layer of your network stack.
In the ``omnetpp.ini`` you can't implement any routing functionality.

Comment: Thanks, do using using UDPBasicApp and modifying it accordingly is a good start?

Comment: I am not familiar with all the applications in INET, so I can't say for sure. But modifying this or writing your own application could be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. For the case of starting a new application do I need to generate makefiles? Thanks

Comment: This is not the place for a conversation or a tutorial how to use OMNeT++. Please study the OMNeT++ manual for such questions: [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/)